# How to create an Custom Object with a Custom Object?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript how would I create a Custom Object that has a property this is another Custom Object.
For Example.

```
function Product() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
}


function Work(values) {
    this.front = values.front || "default";
    this.back = values.back || "default";
    this.product =  Product;
}

var w = new Work();
alert(w.product.prop1); //no worky
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `Product`, like this:

```
function Product() {
    this.prop1 = 1;
    this.prop2 = 2;
}
function Work(values) {
    this.front = values && values.front || "default";
    this.back = values && values.back || "default";
    this.product = new Product();
}
var w = new Work();
alert(w.product.prop1); //1
```

The `front` and `back` changes are a separate issue, since `values` wasn't being passed in  in your example, you'd get an `undefined` error.  [You can test the result here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BA22s/).

---

Here's an alternative way I'd personally use to define those defaults:

```
function Work(values) {
    values = values || { front: "default", back: "default" };
    this.front = values.front;
    this.back = values.back;
    this.product = new Product();
}
```

[You can try that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BA22s/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried that also but it was failing before it got to the alert because of how I was trying to set the front and back properties. Can I ask what "this.front = values && values.front || "default";" does in english?

Comment: @TooFat - It's checking that `values` isn't falsy (`undefined` in this case) before trying to get a property from it, if it's false it'll immediately go to the OR (`||`) and grab the default.